# Why slow worm lost ability to walk in evolution/ecology perpective?

Tags: evolution

Can  lost of legs for [slow worm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anguis_fragilis) be considered as [Batesian mimicry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batesian_mimicry)?

Comment: I just want to be sure why does it lost its  legs.

Comment: Your first link is broken

Comment: For what reason does losing its legs could be an anti-predator adaptation? Can you please explain your thoughts?

Comment: i am sorry but i dont know how to fix this. But anyway i hope this is clear what i am askingfor.

Comment: He is looks like a viper commune, most common poisonous snake in middle europe so i thought that can be possible connection.

Comment: You can use the edit button to fix it. If you are uneasy with the formatting you can see how I fixed it. Can you please explain your thoughts for why being legless in slowworm could be an anti-predator adaptation?

Comment: I thought it is because slow worm looks like a snake and snakes are usually danger with their venom, so part of the slow worm population whose looked more like snake had advantage. In the end the the subtype of slow worm spread in whole species. But  I am quite confused with the part of the lost legs, because it is logicaly much more disadvantage in live (possible trade-off to look like snake?).

Comment: Oh you mean Batesian mimicry then, isn't it? You should edit that!

Comment: @L.Diago Your last comment suggests that a loss of legs is generally a disadvantage. That is hardly the case, since a loss of legs has evolved independently with Squamata multiple times (>20 it seems). With your assuption, you could just as well argue that all snakes should have legs. So the premise of the question is probably incorrect, and mimicry is not likely to be the explanation (at least from what I've seen).

Comment: I actually quite dont see a any diffrence between Batesian mimicry and muller actually (even dont know about batesian). I didnt know that lost of legs was multiple times, but i thought thet slow worm is diffrent case because it is actually lizard. That why i thought this  case is adaptation after the snakes lost legs (secondary). Anyway i got your point with my premise.

Comment: @L.Diago Batesian~= harmless species mimicing dangerous species (eg hoverflies vs wasp) ; müllerian~= several distasteful/poisonous species having warning patterns that resemble eachother.